# Powershell script execution failed

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

```
$hostnames = Get-Content -Path C:\new_folder\machines.txt
ForEach ($server in $hostnames) {
    Write-Host $server
    $server1 = $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$server")).IPAddressToString
    $server1 = $server1.ToString()

    try {
        Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts -Concatenate -Value $server1 -Force
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server1 -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { 'cmd.exe /c C:\bat_start_process\process.bat' } -ErrorAction Stop
    } 
    catch {
        Write-Host 'error'
        $formatstring = "{0} : {1}`n{2}`n" +
        "    + CategoryInfo          : {3}`n" +
        "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : {4}`n"
        $fields = $_.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name,
        $_.ErrorDetails.Message,
        $_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage,
        $_.CategoryInfo.ToString(),
        $_.FullyQualifiedErrorId

        $formatstring -f $fields
    }
}
```

Hi,
I am trying to connect to a remote machine and invoking a bat file. The idea is using this powershell, i should be able to just invoke the bat and leave it running. But i see some error as below.

```
 error
 : [*.*.*.*] Connecting to remote server *.*.*.* failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible ove
r the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the sam
e local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At C:\startBatfile.ps1:19 char:13
+             Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server1 -Credential $Cred - ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (10.233.165.70:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: [How to enable remoting on public networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7.1#how-to-enable-remoting-on-public-networks)

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, you have an issue with the connection to the remote host over WinRM.**

To solve that, you should configure WinRM on both servers.

```
# Just run that cmdlet.    
winrm quickconfig -quiet
```

Then you must have configured TrustedHosts on both servers.
I see that you are doing that on your computer, but what about trustedHost on remote server?

```
# This will set all as trusted
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts *
Restart-Service WinRM
```

And usually required to set an Execution policy, but if you want to run a batch, this is not needed.

**And the Second thing this could not work.**

Why?

Because invoke-command will not execute an interactive process/script on the remote host, it is possible in few ways, but the most simple one is to use [Invoke-CommandAs Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Invoke-CommandAs/3.1.6).

Just run PowerShell as Administrator and run this command.

```
Install-Module -Name Invoke-CommandAs -Force
```

So you doing it like that...

```
Invoke-CommandAs -ComputerName $server1 -ScriptBlock { 'cmd.exe /c C:\bat_start_process\process.bat' }-AsUser $Cred -ErrorAction Stop
```